# Can using do while loop help to improve the efficiency in this scenario?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to produce a programme such that for example if device V is found in column A, it will name the cell that is beside device V to be voltage. The same goes for other devices. Currently, im using if and for loop and i suppose it works well in this case when there are 3 devices. However, in the case where lets say there are 100 devices, i realised that i have to copy and paste then edit the code for 100 times and this can be a tedious process. So i was thinking, does using Do while loop help to improve the efficiency or is there other better way to do it?

Edit: it can also be a case where lets say i already have a list of device with its corresponding alternative name on another worksheet  (not same order like can be device V and voltage on 3rd row instead of 1st row) and i am unsure how to make use of it without having to name it like what i did in my code.

Before

[image]

After running the programme

[image]

```
Dim lastrowt As Long

Dim t As Long

lastrowt = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For t = 1 To lastrowt

If ws1.Range("A" & t) = "device V" Then
ws1.Range("B" & t) = "voltage"
End If

If ws1.Range("A" & t) = "device F" Then
ws1.Range("B" & t) = "Faraday"
End If

If ws1.Range("A" & t) = "device k" Then
ws1.Range("B" & t) = "Kelvin"
End If
Next
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could put the lookup values in another sheet? You could easily do this with a vlookup then. It would also be easy to maintain. If you want to use VBA I would look into the VBA Dictionary class.

Comment: @Kevin Sorry, i didnt explain it clearly so i have posted  pictures of the before and after output of the programme. But ultimately i trying to do it in the VBA way. So how does one do it with VBA dictionary?

Comment: Totally agree with @Kevin, create 2nd sheet with lists of device's in column A and list of those unit in column B, make `Scripting.Dictionary` from it and then in the main sheet use `.Exists` method to check if the name exists in dictionary and then `.Item` to get the value - unit - from dictionary.

Comment: @Teamothy ah i see, so lets say i already have a list of device name and its corresponding name in random order on another worksheet. Is this still applicable?

Comment: I added an example of how to do it with a dictionary. I would still strongly recommend storing the dictionary in another sheet and loading it dynamically.

Comment: @cena see what Kevin made and wrote :)

Comment: @cena - did this work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it with a dictionary (you must add a reference to Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime):

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim lastrowt As Long
    Dim t As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim key As String

    Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    lastrowt = ws1.Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    dict.Add "device V", "Voltage"
    dict.Add "device F", "Faraday"
    dict.Add "device K", "Kelvin"

    For t = 1 To lastrowt
        key = ws1.Range("A" & t)
        If dict.Exists(key) Then
            ws1.Range("B" & t) = dict(key)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this, using the following formula:

```
=IF(A:A="device V";"voltage";IF(A:A="device k";"Kelvin";"Fahrenheit"))
```

The usage of range `A:A` assures that you can use this formula everywhere in the column.